# How to add \and in php for LaTeX output multiple author

Tags: php, latex, author, ieee

PHP code:It just can single author.

```
if ($field == 'author') {
        $newVal = "";
        foreach (@split("\n", $value) as $refEntry) {
            if (strlen(trim($refEntry)) > 0) {
                $newVal .= "\IEEEauthorblockN{{$refEntry}}\n";
            }
        }
        $value = $newVal;
```

How to edit code as below latex script in php that can have \and?

```
\author{\IEEEauthorblockN{Authors Name/s per 1st Affiliation (Author)}
\IEEEauthorblockA{line 1 (of Affiliation): dept. name of organization\\
line 2: name of organization, acronyms acceptable\\
line 3: City, Country\\
line 4: Email: name@xyz.com}
\and
\IEEEauthorblockN{Authors Name/s per 2nd Affiliation (Author)}
\IEEEauthorblockA{line 1 (of Affiliation): dept. name of organization\\
line 2: name of organization, acronyms acceptable\\
line 3: City, Country\\
line 4: Email: name@xyz.com}
}
```